# Mocking RestOperations.exchange in Spock (overloaded method with varargs)

Tags: spring-mvc, mocking, spock

I'm trying to mock `org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations.exchange` in Spock.
Spock fails with

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * restOperations.exchange("https://test.com", HttpMethod.POST, _ as HttpEntity, String)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * restOperations.exchange('https://test.com', POST, <whatever,[]>, class java.lang.String, [])
```

I think the problem is related to the fact that the `exchange` method is overloaded and the version I'm trying to call has vararg arguments.

How do I define this interaction, so the test succeeds?

MySubject.java:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;

public class MySubject {
    private final RestOperations rest;

    public MySubject(RestOperations rest) {
        this.rest = rest;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>("whatever");
        rest.exchange("https://test.com", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity);
    }
}
```

MyTest.groovy:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyTest extends Specification {
    RestOperations restOperations = Mock(RestOperations)
    MySubject subject = new MySubject(restOperations)

    def "test"() {
        when:
        subject.doStuff()
        then:
        1 * restOperations.exchange("https://test.com", HttpMethod.POST, _ as HttpEntity, String)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

1. In the application you import `org.springframework.http.HttpEntity`, in the test `org.apache.http.HttpEntity`. You need to correct that.
2. The call `rest.exchange("https://test.com", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity);` in your application does not even compile because there is no such signature in the `RestOperations` class. You need to add the parameter `String.class`.
3. In the test you need to reflect the method signature including the varargs, i.e. the real method signature has 5 arguments.

If you fix all of these your test runs smoothly:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q61135628;

import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;

public class MySubject {
  private final RestOperations rest;

  public MySubject(RestOperations rest) {
    this.rest = rest;
  }

  public void doStuff() {
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>("whatever");
    rest.exchange("https://test.com", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q61135628

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyTest extends Specification {
  RestOperations restOperations = Mock()
  MySubject subject = new MySubject(restOperations)

  def "test"() {
    when:
    subject.doStuff()

    then:
    1 * restOperations.exchange("https://test.com", HttpMethod.POST, _, String, _)
    // Or if you want to be more specific:
//  1 * restOperations.exchange("https://test.com", HttpMethod.POST, _, String, [])
  }
}
```